Encountered 429 error "Quota exceeded for online_prediction_concurrent_requests_per_base_model" when using Claude 3 Haiku

I am using Claude 3 Haiku on Vertex AI and occasionally encounter the following error message:

{
  "code": 429,
  "message": "Quota exceeded for aiplatform.googleapis.com/online_prediction_concurrent_requests_per_base_model. Please submit a quota increase request.",
  "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}


The error message indicates that the quota for online_prediction_concurrent_requests_per_base_model has been exceeded. However, I am only making a few requests (less than 5) per minute.

I have checked the Vertex AI quota page but cannot find any information about this specific quota.

The quota for base_model : anthropic-claude-3-haiku-20240307 is 60 requests per minute.

I believe the error message refers to a different quota, possibly concurrent_requests_per_base_model, which is not listed on the quota page.

I have searched for information about the concurrent_requests_per_base_model quota but have not been able to find anything.

I have checked the Vertex AI documentation but have not found any relevant information.




Can you please provide information about the concurrent_requests_per_base_model quota?
Is there a way to increase this quota?
How can I avoid encountering this error in the future?


update:
Thank you for your response regarding the online_prediction_concurrent_requests_per_base_model quota error I'm encountering with Claude 3 Haiku on Vertex AI.
I understand that the online_prediction_requests_per_base_model quota refers to the QPM (query per minute) limit, which is 60 QPM for my region according to the documentation. However, the error I'm receiving specifically mentions online_prediction_concurrent_requests_per_base_model, which seems to be a different quota related to concurrent requests.
I've been conducting tests with several projects simultaneously, each with a low QPM (5-20), yet I still encounter the 429 error when the total combined QPM reaches a certain threshold. This leads me to believe that the issue is related to concurrent requests rather than the per-model request limit.
I've also ruled out the possibility of Free Tier limitations as I've been using a paid account for over six months.
I'm still investigating the concurrent_requests_per_base_model quota and will provide updates if I find any relevant information.
Thank you again for your time and assistance.

In addition to the answer by @gang-chen, you should always implement Exponential Backoff and retry the request.

The error message tells you the solution: Please submit a quota increase request. Double-check that you do not have a billing issue. Then update your question after Google updates your quota.

I have double-checked the billing issue and can confirm that I am not on the free tier. I am paying thousands of dollars per month for this account.

I would like to check my quota for online_prediction_concurrent_requests_per_base_model , but there is no quota section for this metric. Could you please provide instructions on how to check my quota for this metric?

online_prediction_requests_per_base_model is the quota identifier for the Claude 3 model QPM (query per minute). Different GCP regions may have different quota. For example, document here lists the Claude 3 Opus (preview) quota for us-central1 is 60 QPM.
You should be able to look up your quota in GCP console. From the GCP menu bar, select IAM & Admin -> Quotas & System Limits. Then, type online_prediction in the Filter bar. You should see the apiplatform.googleapis.com/online_prediction_requests_per_base_model quota. Select it will show all regions quotas.

Verify that quota for your region. You can request quota increase using the edit quota action on top of the page.
Again, your quota and consumption could be determined by several other factors such as Free tier users, others in the same project making request etc.

While I've provided a detailed update above, I haven't yet found a definitive solution. I'm currently using exponential backoff to mitigate the issue and will continue to share any further insights as I learn more. Thanks again for your interest.

Saw your update and updated my answer: I can only search for online_prediction_requests_per_base_model. Are you using streaming option when making the inference (prediction) request? Try to disable streaming for testing. In the meantime, open a support case (ticket, you can do that in console) for online_prediction_concurrent_requests_per_base_model investigation.

Are you using a free account? Free tier accounts have some quota restrictions.
Please check below link once which have details on quota :
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/partner-models/use-claude#anthropic_claude_quotas_and_supported_context_length

This answer isn't about figuring out which limit you are hitting, rather a convenient way to handle any of them.
The Claude SDK (if you're using it) actually handles this internally in a really nice way by exposing max_retries and timeout parameters so in my case it was enough to push those up to much higher values in my Python code:
client = AnthropicVertex(
    max_retries=99,
    timeout=httpx.Timeout(1800, connect=1800, read=1800, write=1800),
    ...
)

If you're calling the API directly, you could implement similar strategies, i.e. retrying with an exponential backoff until timeout.
There's also a daily token limit though, which isn't really possible to gracefully handle.
